# Объединение нескольких таблиц в меню

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `prefix_categories` (
  `cat_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `num_sort` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cat_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `slug` (`slug`),
  UNIQUE KEY `num_sort` (`num_sort`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `prefix_link` (
  `link_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `num_sort` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`link_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `slug` (`slug`,`num_sort`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `prefix_menu` (
  `menu_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `slug` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`menu_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `slug` (`slug`,`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `prefix_pages` (
  `page_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `num_sort` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`page_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `slug` (`slug`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Выше привел созданную мной БД

Как реализовать меню на основе этих таблиц?

есть категории/страницы/ссылки разумеется поля у них тоже будут добавляться но четыре стандартных все же будут, хотелось бы не просто склеить их а вывести иерархию к примеру:

категория
  ссылка
    категория
  страница
ссылка
  категория
    страница
      ссылка
    страница

как реализовать задуманное? Для начала архитектуру БД и сам запрос, можно ли это сделать одним запросом? и какую нагрузку будет давать этот запрос?

Comment: добавить всем еще 1 поле page_id и создать табличку многие ко многим где page_id_up => page_id_down , ну и все , далее просто раскидать какая сущность к какой относится , ну индекс на это поле кинуть .

Comment: не совсем Вас понял, а как же быть с сортировками? и родителями?
что бы потом клеить все в :
  
категория  
   страница  
      страница  
   ссылка  
      категория  
страница  
   страница  
   страница

Comment: page_id_up родитель

Comment: можно в виде запроса? как должна выглядеть таблица многие ко многим и зачем там индекс?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Ну я имел в виду , что то вот такое , то есть простое дерево , где id это page_id_up , parent page_id_down и type это тип страницы (материала) , вам просто нужно связать их меж собой .

```
--------------
id parent type
--------------
 3      0  1
 5      0  1
 7      0  1
10      3  2
11      7  2
12      5  3
13      3  3
16     10  1
21     16  1
26     11  1
30      3  2
47      7  4
60     10  5
73     13  6
75     47  1
---------
o- 3
|
+-o- 10
| |
| +-o- 16
| | |
| | +-o- 21
| |
| +-o- 60
|
+-o- 13
| |
| +-o- 73
|
+-o- 30

o- 5
|
+-o- 12

o- 7
|
+-o- 11
| |
| +-o- 26
|
+-o- 47
  |
  +-o- 75
```

Comment: теперь более понятно, но все же, а как осуществить связку по type сразу с тремя таблицами? можете привести запрос?

Comment: ну мапить 1 - prefix_categories , 2 - prefix_link 3 - prefix_pages ... etc ,  Тем более если у вас все  таблицы учавствуют в раскладке меню , то просто дергаете их все разом `SELECT * FROM prefix_link a , prefix_categories b, prefix_pages c ` , далее делаете реиндекс массива по полю type и рекурсивно собираете менюшку , походу выдергивая из массива название итемов , реиндекс для того что бы не рытся в массиве , а брать напрямую `$arr[id] `

Comment: 1 раз соберете , закешите и все ок

Comment: а как можно закешировать?

Comment: Ну это уже вам решать , можете в файлик menu.tpl , можете в тот же мускул сунуть как текст , все проще потом выдернуть `SELECT value FROM cache WHERE key = 'main_menu' ` чем 3 таблицы и рекурсия по ним .

Comment: С кешированием более менее понятно, но вот запрос никак составить не могу, две таблицы соединял а вот три в голову не лезут. И что такое реиндекс? в PHP постараюсь разобраться, а вот с запросом MySQL помогите). SELECT * FROM prefix_link a , prefix_categories b, prefix_pages c, а далее как объединить? using? left join? и в чем будет разница? можете привести полный запрос?

Comment: А зачем вообще 4 таблички ? они же у вас однотипные , или это такой шардинг ? типа данных будет тааак много что если держать все в 1 то никакой индекс не спасет ? так то гораздо проще добавить еще 1 поле  type и держать все в 1 таблице .